# Which is the best way to access COM interfaces from a J2EE server?

Tags: java, com, jakarta-ee, com-interop

Are the available Java-COM bridges like j-Integra, com4j and Jacob and others suitable to be used in a J2EE container? Which one is the most appropriate for that use? I need to evaluate the risk of JVM crashes, native memory leak and unmanaged thread creation (since it's not recommended in a J2EE container that uses thread pools) for the available Java-COM bridges available today.

Comment: I've done some research and found the j-Interop library that does not use native code (it's pure Java using RPC). It seems to be a more suitable solution for use on a J2EE server than the others Java-COM bridges.

Comment: You have the option of posting your comment as an answer to your question. You're even free to accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Adam: I've posted a comment instead of an answer because I'm not sure yet if j-Interop can be considered "J2EE friendly".

Comment: During my tests I've found out that j-Interop starts unmanaged child threads. This is not ideal to use in a J2EE server with threads managed by a thread pool.

Answer (score 5):

I've used those bridges you mentioned. I would chose a very different approach, because of the things you said: crashes, mem leaks, and a lot of other stuff.

I would have a little Windows Server, using COM components since it is its native environment. In that little Windows Server you can expose some HTTP interfaces (WEB requests) you can use in your Java EE server to access COM components through Windows Server. That Windows Server can be an IIS with ASP.NET server, or a custom made program with a proprietary protocol you can write in C#, C++, C, VB.NET.

It's in my opinion, your safest choice. It will save you a lot of headaches when you go to production mode.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. A Web Service on IIS could safely encapsulate the COM interface to the J2EE server.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason you need to use JAVA-COM bridge is you need some Windows based functionality which is not available in Unix based system. Few years back it was no MS WORD, EXCEL JAVA APIs were available on Unix. So if possible try to use native JAVA APIs to achieve Windows based functionality. Like using APACHE POI. Setting J-Integra on machine with high security settings is tricky and needs special considerations.